# Distribution of 1D random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

For 1D random walk starting at 0 with probability $p$ up one step and $q$ down one step, let $T_k$ be the random variable that counts the number of steps for a path to first reach $k$.

It feels like $T_2-T_1$ should be identically distributed with $T_1$, but this doesn't seem to be true. I got $P(T_2-T_1=t)=rP(T_1=t)$, where $r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(T_1=n)$, i.e. $r$ is the probability of reaching 1 eventually (which is smaller than 1 if $p<0.5$). What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's smaller than 1 if $p<0.5$. Why is the sum independent of $p$? If $p<0.5$ there's a non zero chance of never reaching 1. The sum is just the probability of eventually reaching 1.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I assume you did this? $P(T_2-T_1=t)=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} P(T_2=i+t|T_1=i)P(T_1=i)=P(T_1=t)\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}P(T_1=i)$

Comment: Yes. I realized $T_2-T_1$ cannot be identically distributed, by definition $T_2-T_1=\infty$ iff $T_2=\infty$, which has probability $1-r^2$. Probabilities add up to $1$, so $\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(T_2-T_1=t)+P(T_2-T_1=\infty)=1$, so if it was identically distributed as $T_1$ then the LHS adds up to $r+1-r^2\neq 1$.